# Getting exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed while trying to save secound istance

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am learning hibernate. Everything is preaty clear at the beegining, however when I try to run my app and in main I have two operation connected with session I get exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
```

Below you can find my DBManager class where I habe methods for adding instances to DB:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class DBManager
{
    public void addAutor(String name, String lastName, Book book)
    {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Autor autor = new Autor(name,lastName,book);
        session.save(autor);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
    }
    public Book addBook(int ISBN, String name, String autorName)
    {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Book book = new Book(ISBN,name,autorName);
        session.save(book);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
        return book;
    }
}
```

Here is my HibernateUtil class for configuration of the session:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Autor.class);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Book.class);
            configuration.configure();

            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder standardServiceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
            standardServiceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = standardServiceRegistryBuilder.build();

            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

And finally the main class:

```
public class Test
{

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        DBManager dbManager = new DBManager();
        Book book =  dbManager.addBook(1,"Hobbit","Tolkien");
        dbManager.addAutor("JRR","Tolkien",book);
    }
}
```

As you can see I just put book, and than try to put Autor. What could be the reason for exception from secound method? I suppose that I do sth. wrong with closing and opening of the session, however I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I found the sulution myself:

I have created the one sessionFactory object for whole class DBManager:

```
private final SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
```

So in every method I open session, and than close at the end, eg:

```
    public void addAutor(String name, String lastName, Book book)
    {
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Autor autor = new Autor(name,lastName,book);
        session.save(autor);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

Maybe someone will face the same problem.

Comment: You really don't need deal with session manually this way since you have used Hibernate. It will deal with it automatically. Good to know you have resolve it.